# Does $\operatorname{card} \operatorname{ran} f \leq \operatorname{card} \operatorname{dom} f$ imply choice?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I am considering the following statement:

*If $f$ is a function, then $\operatorname{card} \operatorname{ran} f \leq \operatorname{card} \operatorname{dom} f$.*

This can be proved using the axiom of choice. Since $f^{-1}$ is a relation, the axiom of choice implies that there is a function $g \subseteq f^{-1}$ with $\operatorname{dom} g = \operatorname{dom} f^{-1} (= \operatorname{ran} f)$. We have $\operatorname{ran} g \subseteq \operatorname{ran} f^{-1} = \operatorname{dom} f$. Also, $g(x) = g(y)$ implies $x = f(g(x)) = f(g(y)) = y$, so $g$ is one-to-one. Thus, there is a one-to-one function from $\operatorname{ran} f$ into $\operatorname{dom} f$.

What I am wondering about is this: does the above statement imply the axiom of choice, so that they are equivalent?

Comment: Sorry it took so long, my network hanged.

Comment: There are a lot more relevant questions. I'll leave you to find them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very quick answer! @AsafKaragila

Comment: Well, this is one of my favorite problems in set theory...